# What determines the vertical space in Reportlab tables?

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm defining this style in the document:

```
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Table Header', font ='Helvetica-Bold',fontSize=16, alignment=TA_CENTER))
```

I use this to define paragraphs for text to go into the top row of each table (so that they wrap correctly):

```
L2sub = [(Paragraph(L[0][0], styles['Table Header']))]
```

Later, when I add a table, there's also a place to define styles:

```
report.append(Table(data,style=[
                ('GRID',(0,0),(len(topiclist)-1,-1),0.5,colors.grey),
                ('FONT', (0,0),(len(topiclist)-1,0),'Helvetica-Bold',16),
                ('FONT', (0,1),(len(topiclist)-1,1),'Helvetica-Bold',12),
                ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                ('SPAN',(0,0),(len(topiclist)-1,0)),
                ]))
```

**My question is:** where is the setting that defines the vertical height of the cells on the first row? I'm having some issues with text being too large for the cell and/or being set too low in the cell, but I can't pin down what's causing it or what to do to fix it. I've changed both sizes, but I can't get the cells to be anything other than all the same height. When I just put text into the cells instead of paragraphs, the table def'n worked nicely, but the paragraphs caused the problem.

Comment: My understanding is that if you don't use paragraphs, and put text in the table cells directly, then wrapping can happen automatically. Paragraphs, having wrapping logic of their own, need a fixed space in which to work. So why are you using paragraphs "so that they wrap correctly"?

Comment: That wasn't my experience: I had tables going past the bounds of the page because they weren't wrapping, until I put the text into paragraphs. I got that idea from another SO question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe there's a setting in `TableStyle` that allows you to change rowheight. That measurement is given when you're creating a new `Table` object:

```
Table(data, colwidths, rowheights)
```

Where `colwidths` and `rowheights` are lists of measurement values, like so:

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.platypus import Table
from reportlab.lib import colors

# Creates a table with 2 columns, variable width
colwidths = [2.5*inch, .8*inch]

# Two rows with variable height
rowheights = [.4*inch, .2*inch]

table_style = [
    ('GRID', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
    ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
    ('ALIGN', (1, 1), (1, -1), 'RIGHT')
]

style = getSampleStyleSheet()

title_paragraph = Paragraph(
    "<font size=13><b>My Title Here</b></font>",
    style["Normal"]
)
# Just filling in the first row
data = [[title_paragraph, 'Random text string']]

# Now we can create the table with our data, and column/row measurements
table = Table(data, colwidths, rowheights)

# Another way of setting table style, using the setStyle method.
table.setStyle(tbl_style)

report.append(table)
```

`colwidths` and `rowheights` can be changed to whatever measurement you need to fit the content. `colwidths` reads left to right, and `rowheights` reads top to bottom.

If you know that all of your table rows are going to be the same height, you can use this nice shortcut:

```
rowheights = [.2*inch] * len(data)
```

Which gives you a list like `[.2*inch, .2*inch, ...]` for every row in your `data` variable.

Answer (score 10):

(Don't have enough reputation to comment the other answer)

Regarding the last shortcut, simply "ROW_HEIGHT = 5 * mm" is working. No need to multiply the row height per the number of row in the table.

```
ROW_HEIGHT = 5 * mm
curr_table = Table(data, COL_WIDTHS, rowHeights=ROW_HEIGH )
```

Saves a bit of memory. :)

Comment: That's neat. Have some rep. ;)